# Shiny Check box dynamic values from output (Server.r)

Tags: r, shiny, checkboxlist

Edit: Full code

Data File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_sB3ef_9RntOWJjNlhrUjk3a1k/view
Not sure how to share data files in stackoverflow. So gave an attachment in Google drive. Please let me know if there is any alternative.

I am having trouble creating dynamic check box filter in Shiny App based on the input csv data. I need user to input the data file (.csv) and use the column "Country" in that file to appear as a check box filter in the UI. However, I am getting errors.

Here is my code. I tried different ways but of no use. Please help!

Server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {     

    data_attr <- reactive({
      file1 <- input$file_attr
      if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
      list(read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors))

    })

  countries <- reactive({
    if(is.null(data_attr()$Country)){return()}
    data_attr()$Country
  })

  output$CountryList <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data_attr()$Country)){return()}
    checkboxGroupInput('show_vars', 'Country Filter',
                       as.list(countries))
  })

})
```

UI.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  navbarPage(

    "Tab_name",
    tabPanel("Engine",
             bootstrapPage(
               div(style="display:inline-block", fileInput("file_attr", "attributes:")),
               uiOutput("CountryList")
             )

    )
  )
))
```

Error:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4017
Warning: Error in !: invalid argument type
Stack trace (innermost first):
    92: read.table
    91: <reactive:data_attr> [C:\Users\userName\Documents\dummt/server.R#8]
    80: data_attr
    79: renderUI [C:\Users\userName\Documents\dummt/server.R#18]
    78: func
    77: origRenderFunc
    76: output$CountryList
     1: runApp
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample data?. Also provide a code which would reproduce the error. With this code snippet its hard to figure what is the error in the code.

Comment: Provided UI and Server codes and Sample data in Google drive. Hope that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you were getting was because your read .table `read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)` had `input$sep`, `input$header` and `input$stringAsFactors`  tha are undefined UI input elements and hence the value is NULL. For now I have given hard coded values for those. You can define the UI elements if you desire that later.

Apart from that I have modified your code so that you get the output as desired. I have added an observeEvent for `input$file_attr` so that render UI is triggered after you upload the file.

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {     
  data_attr <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file_attr
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=",",, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  })

  countries <- reactive({

    if(is.null(data_attr()$Country)){return()}
    data_attr()$Country
  })


  observeEvent(input$file_attr, {
    output$CountryList <- renderUI({
      if(is.null(data_attr()$Country)){return()}
      checkboxGroupInput('show_vars', 'Country Filter',
                         countries())
    })

  }) 

})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: THANKS A LOT!! was struggling to resolve this for many hours. This solution is exactly what I am looking for :)

Comment: Hi, can you please look at the followup question based on the code you gave. Its in a different context, so posted as a separate question-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740175/shiny-updateselectizeinput-is-throwing-the-error-operator-is-invalid-for-ato
Thanks!