# Shiny: updateSelectizeInput is throwing the error "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I am new to shiny and having hard time to figure this out. I am trying to create a "Select ALL" button in my selectizeInput but I am getting an error while passing the input from selectizeInput to the updateSelectizeInput. Could someone please help me to resolve this.

**When I select "Select ALL" from the input box**, the App closes and shows the error: "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

I added "Select All" in the input field (selectizeInput()). When an user clicks "Select All", updateSelectizeInput() adds the set difference between all names in the input and "Select All", populating the filter box with all values.

Data for the script: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_sB3ef_9RntOWJjNlhrUjk3a1k/view

Here is my Script

UI.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    "Tab_name",
    tabPanel("Engine",
             bootstrapPage(
               div(style="display:inline-block", fileInput("file_attr", "attributes:")),
               uiOutput("CountryList")
             )         
    )
  )
))
```

Server.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {     
  data_attr <- reactive({
      file1 <- input$file_attr
      if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
      read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)       
    })

    countries <- reactive({
      if(is.null(data_attr()$Country)){return()}
      data_attr()$Country
    })  

    observeEvent(input$file_attr, {
      output$CountryList <- renderUI({
        if(is.null(data_attr()$Country)){return()}
        selectizeInput('show_vars', 'Country Filter', choices = c("Select All",unique(countries())), multiple = TRUE)
      })
    }) 

    observe({
      if ("Select All" %in% input$show_vars){
        selected_choices <- setdiff(c("Select All",unique(countries())), "Select All")
        updateSelectizeInput('show_vars', 'Country Filter', selected = selected_choices)

      }

    })

  })
```

Error comes when we select "select all" from the input field of the UI

```
Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Stack trace (innermost first):
    58: updateSelectInput
    57: updateSelectizeInput
    56: observerFunc [C:\Users\naresh.ambati\Documents\dummt/server.R#30]
     1: runApp
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because you have got the arguments to be passed to the update `updateSelectizeInput` is incorrect. You need to pass the `session` object as the first argument. In your case it should be something like this:

`updateSelectizeInput(session,'show_vars', 'Country Filter', selected = selected_choices)`

And while you define the server function you need to pass `session` object as follows:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 

.......

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Many thanks @SBista ...It's strange to get an atomic-vector-error when such a thing is no where in the code. May be some internal thing in session.

Comment: That error i think is because `show_vars` is an atomic vector while `session` is a list and you can't access atomic vectors using `$` operator